# Windows Offline Files - where's the information stored?

Tags: windows-vista, offline-files

Where can I find and manipulate the information *which files and folders* have been marked as "Always Available Offline" without using Windows Explorer? I don't want or need to access the offline files\folders themselves, I just want to remotely set the offline folders for some of my users.
(Windows Vista in a Domain)

Answer (score 1):

The cached offline files are not accessible for users and administrators. AFAIK they are stored in a database inside `C:\Windows\CSC`.

Additional offline folders can be added via registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

```
\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\AssignedOfflineFolders
```

Add the UNC path of the folder to be included into offline files as `REG_SZ` entry

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. The currently marked files and folders are not stored in that regkey and adding new folders was not my intention. Anyway, still learned something new :) And besides, the offline files _are_ accessible for admins (the whole folder structure is stored 1:1 in that CSC folder), it's just not what I need...